# Adafruit INA219 module, shunt voltage values and calibration

Tags: arduino

I'm using the Adafruit INA219 module to measure voltage and current to a linear actuator, and I have a question about how to best calibrate the module to my situation.

I have a 12V power supply (similar looking to a power brick for a laptop) that has a max current rating of 10A.  The actuator is rated for 12V @ 5A maximum, delivering a force of 35lbs.  I'm using the MegaMoto driver shield to drive the actuator, and an Arduino Nano as the controller.

The default calibration for the INA219 module seems to be for 32V @ 2A, and it has some other settings available via function calls [here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_INA219/blob/master/Adafruit_INA219.cpp), but I don't see anything that fits with a 12V @ 5A situation, and am not sure what to use for the various values if I was to write a new function to calibrate the INA219.  Anybody know what I can use?

I was hoping I'd have accurate readings out of the box on this module for what I needed, but instead I'm getting some pretty wide value swings and some odd(?) shunt voltage values (or very possibly, I just don't understand them).  For example, when moving the actuator, I'm reading the values from the module every 1ms for 15ms, then averaging out the power usage and using that as a way to filter out the highs and lows to see what the general power usage is.  I'm using the equations from the example code:

```
shuntvoltage = ina219.getShuntVoltage_mV();
busvoltage = ina219.getBusVoltage_V();
current_mA = ina219.getCurrent_mA();
loadvoltage = busvoltage + (shuntvoltage / 1000);
power = current_mA * loadvoltage;
```

Here's an example of a reading:

> shuntvoltage: -31.76
> busvoltage: 12.16
> current_mA: -258.60
> loadvoltage: 12.13
> power: -3137.40
>
> shuntvoltage: -59.12
> busvoltage: 12.16
> current_mA: -548.50
> loadvoltage: 12.10
> power: -6637.33
>
> shuntvoltage: -52.00
> busvoltage: 12.18
> current_mA: -691.30
> loadvoltage: 12.12
> power: -8381.32
>
> shuntvoltage: -32.09
> busvoltage: 12.12
> current_mA: -936.60
> loadvoltage: 12.09
> power: -11321.54
>
> shuntvoltage: -27.42
> busvoltage: 12.11
> current_mA: -286.00
> loadvoltage: 12.08
> power: -3455.05
>
> shuntvoltage: -86.82
> busvoltage: 12.11
> current_mA: -338.90
> loadvoltage: 12.03
> power: -4075.33
>
> shuntvoltage: -67.63
> busvoltage: 12.16
> current_mA: -620.90
> loadvoltage: 12.09
> power: -7508.15
>
> shuntvoltage: -30.81
> busvoltage: 12.18
> current_mA: -874.60
> loadvoltage: 12.15
> power: -10625.68
>
> shuntvoltage: -30.31
> busvoltage: 12.11
> current_mA: -346.90
> loadvoltage: 12.08
> power: -4189.75
>
> shuntvoltage: -71.75
> busvoltage: 12.16
> current_mA: -557.00
> loadvoltage: 12.09
> power: -6733.16
>
> shuntvoltage: -48.03
> busvoltage: 12.18
> current_mA: -668.70
> loadvoltage: 12.13
> power: -8112.65
>
> shuntvoltage: -31.90
> busvoltage: 12.18
> current_mA: -938.20
> loadvoltage: 12.15
> power: -11397.35
>
> shuntvoltage: -30.14
> busvoltage: 12.12
> current_mA: -627.20
> loadvoltage: 12.09
> power: -7580.25
>
> shuntvoltage: -31.42
> busvoltage: 12.14
> current_mA: -430.20
> loadvoltage: 12.10
> power: -5207.39
>
> shuntvoltage: -66.28
> busvoltage: 12.17
> current_mA: -643.70
> loadvoltage: 12.10
> power: -7789.88
>
> shuntvoltage: -30.93
> busvoltage: 12.18
> current_mA: -880.00
> loadvoltage: 12.15
> power: -10694.70

Why are the shunt voltage values negatives? And the current values?  Maybe I just need to reverse the polarity.

Here's the specs on the actuator: http://www.progressiveautomations.com/media/catalog/pdf/Linear_Actuator_with_Potentiometer_PA-14P.pdf

Comment: Could you please use proper units? lbs is some weird medievel unit for mass. Outside the USA (yes there is something outside) everybody uses Newtons as the unit of Force. Its 2016....

Comment: At least I didn't use stone? =)  In all fairness, I'm just using the unit used by the actuator manufacturer (some near-Murica country, I think in the Great White North?), and I've edited my post to include a link to their specs.

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina219.pdf,

Comment: I had read most of that in other places already, a bit of information overload. The part in there about the calibration, it's over my head and I'm hoping somebody can break down how to use the driver library that I linked to above, that has a function call to calibrate the device, but I'm not sure how to set that call up (probably need to write a custom function with values that match the 12V @ 5A situation I have)

Comment: Well that's the problem of being spoonfed with code. Once you have to think yourself you are doomed. I highly recommend that you solve this little puzzle yourself. it will feel incredibly good once you succeed. Give it a try. It's the only way to improve. You got all information and even a sample implementation from that guy. If you hit a specific problem you can ask someone. I assume you did not even counter-check the results with a multimeter? otherwise I cannot explain the question on negative values.

Comment: If I had more time on this project, I'd be more than happy to learn all the intricacies, but I'm pretty much at the end of my timeframe for delivery.  I did get the negative values issue solved, it was just a polarity issue (found by MM checking, in fact). If I had all the time I wanted, I could have taken the time to build my own circuit, write my own driver code, etc., but I didn't for this project and was hoping for a good spoonful of prepackaged answer from somebody familiar with this module and the Adafruit code.  The system works well enough now for delivery, but was hoping for more.

Comment: Sorry but I have problems undestanding what you don't understand. The adafruit code gives  3 explicit examples on how to calculate the parameters for a voltage/current range. They explain it line by line. What part is it you don't get?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about calibrating electronics components and not about programming as defined in the [help] pages.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extract from the Adafruit code. It shows how to calculate  the parameters. An information you also find explained in the INA219 datasheet.
This is an example of how to setup the IC for 16V 400mA.

```
void Adafruit_INA219::setCalibration_16V_400mA(void) {

  // Calibration which uses the highest precision for 
  // current measurement (0.1mA), at the expense of 
  // only supporting 16V at 400mA max.

  // VBUS_MAX = 16V
  // VSHUNT_MAX = 0.04          (Assumes Gain 1, 40mV)
  // RSHUNT = 0.1               (Resistor value in ohms)

  // 1. Determine max possible current
  // MaxPossible_I = VSHUNT_MAX / RSHUNT
  // MaxPossible_I = 0.4A

  // 2. Determine max expected current
  // MaxExpected_I = 0.4A

  // 3. Calculate possible range of LSBs (Min = 15-bit, Max = 12-bit)
  // MinimumLSB = MaxExpected_I/32767
  // MinimumLSB = 0.0000122              (12uA per bit)
  // MaximumLSB = MaxExpected_I/4096
  // MaximumLSB = 0.0000977              (98uA per bit)

  // 4. Choose an LSB between the min and max values
  //    (Preferrably a roundish number close to MinLSB)
  // CurrentLSB = 0.00005 (50uA per bit)

  // 5. Compute the calibration register
  // Cal = trunc (0.04096 / (Current_LSB * RSHUNT))
  // Cal = 8192 (0x2000)

  ina219_calValue = 8192;

  // 6. Calculate the power LSB
  // PowerLSB = 20 * CurrentLSB
  // PowerLSB = 0.001 (1mW per bit)

  // 7. Compute the maximum current and shunt voltage values before overflow
  //
  // Max_Current = Current_LSB * 32767
  // Max_Current = 1.63835A before overflow
  //
  // If Max_Current > Max_Possible_I then
  //    Max_Current_Before_Overflow = MaxPossible_I
  // Else
  //    Max_Current_Before_Overflow = Max_Current
  // End If
  //
  // Max_Current_Before_Overflow = MaxPossible_I
  // Max_Current_Before_Overflow = 0.4
  //
  // Max_ShuntVoltage = Max_Current_Before_Overflow * RSHUNT
  // Max_ShuntVoltage = 0.04V
  //
  // If Max_ShuntVoltage >= VSHUNT_MAX
  //    Max_ShuntVoltage_Before_Overflow = VSHUNT_MAX
  // Else
  //    Max_ShuntVoltage_Before_Overflow = Max_ShuntVoltage
  // End If
  //
  // Max_ShuntVoltage_Before_Overflow = VSHUNT_MAX
  // Max_ShuntVoltage_Before_Overflow = 0.04V

  // 8. Compute the Maximum Power
  // MaximumPower = Max_Current_Before_Overflow * VBUS_MAX
  // MaximumPower = 0.4 * 16V
  // MaximumPower = 6.4W

  // Set multipliers to convert raw current/power values
  ina219_currentDivider_mA = 20;  // Current LSB = 50uA per bit (1000/50 = 20)
  ina219_powerDivider_mW = 1;     // Power LSB = 1mW per bit

  // Set Calibration register to 'Cal' calculated above 
  wireWriteRegister(INA219_REG_CALIBRATION, ina219_calValue);

  // Set Config register to take into account the settings above
  uint16_t config = INA219_CONFIG_BVOLTAGERANGE_16V |
                    INA219_CONFIG_GAIN_1_40MV |
                    INA219_CONFIG_BADCRES_12BIT |
                    INA219_CONFIG_SADCRES_12BIT_1S_532US |
                    INA219_CONFIG_MODE_SANDBVOLT_CONTINUOUS;
  wireWriteRegister(INA219_REG_CONFIG, config);
}
```

Let's start with the max bus voltage. You have a 12V power supply so we stick with the 16V of the example (you can choose  between 16V and 32V)
The shunt resistor value is 0.1 Ohms for the Adafruit board.
Your actuator draws 5A at max load. Ohms law tells us that max current will cause a voltage drop across the shunt resistor of 0.5V, so our VSHUNT_MAX is 0.5

Now calculate the LSB value for the current measurement.
5A / 32767LSB = 150µA per LSB (of course you can choose something else if you don't need full resolution)

Compute the calibration  register according to the formula in the datasheet:
Cal = trunc (0.04096 / 0.00015 / 0.1) = 2730

And so on... I hope you get the point.